# PrimeFaces DragDropEvent NullPointerException

Tags: primefaces, nullpointerexception, drag-and-drop

Even so my question is pretty similar to another question, it's not exactly the same.

My current XHTML looks like this:

```
<p:dataGrid id="availableAttachments" value="#{orgUnitCRBean.orgUnit.attachments}" var="attachment" varStatus="status">
    <p:draggable revert="true" for="attachmentButton#{status.index}" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true"/>
    <p:panel toggleable="false" disabled="false" id="attachmentButton#{status.index}" readonly="false" rendered="true" title="#{attachment.fileName}" value="#{attachment.fileName}">
        <p:commandButton ajax="false" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true" value="#{attachment.fileName}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{orgUnitCRBean.handleFileDownload(attachment)}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:panel>
</p:dataGrid>
<p:droppable activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" dataSource="availableAttachments" tolerance="touch" for="attachmentPanel" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true">
    <p:ajax listener="#{orgUnitCRBean.handleFileDelete}" update="@form" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true"/>
</p:droppable>
```

And the Bean like this:

```
/*
* Delete an attachment.
*/
public void handleFileDelete(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {

 Attachment attachment = ((Attachment) ddEvent.getData());
 System.out.println("Attachment: " + attachment);
 UUID id = attachment.getId();
 String idToBeDeleted = attachment.getId().toString();
}
```

The DragDropEvent doesn't contain any data, so I get a NullPointerException here. From my point of view I'm really close to the showcase from PrimeFaces. Found a couple of similar questions on the net, but no suitable answer. Maybe someone knows what to do, over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still got no idea, why the data Object is null, but my work-around is now the "dragId" of the DragDropEvent, which can be used to figure out, which object has been dragged on the drop zone.